# Pick which browser window to open a new tab in

Tags: javascript, html

Typically when creating the markup for `anchor` tags in HTML, you can set a `target` attribute on the DOM node to specify how this link should open when clicked—in a new tab, in the current tab, etc.

Let's say, for example, I have two Chrome windows open. `Window A` is on my left on its own monitor, and `window B` is to my right, also on its own monitor. I have a custom `new tab` page that allows me quick access to links I visit the most frequently. It also has a big clock so I always know what time it is while I'm writing code. These links currently only open in a new tab in the same window.

Is it possible then to click a link in `window A`, and have it open as a new tab in `window B` so that I still have unobstructed access to my custom new tab page?

Comment: @Sphinx — It's similar, but not the same. This is asking for a new tab in an existing window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

("Browser context" refers to a viewport with associated gubbins, typically a tab or window depending on the browser and OS).

You can:

- Open in an existing, named, browser context
- Open in a new, named or unnamed, browser content

The most control over where and what that context is, is to use JavaScript's `open()` method to specify the height and width, which will trigger a new window instead of a new tab in most desktop browsers.

There is no way to override the user preference to trigger a new tab instead of a new window. There is no way to determine where a new tab will appear.

Comment: Gubbins? What is that?

Comment: "Miscellaneous items; paraphernalia." — https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/gubbins